# What are the different colors and what are their main characteristics?

Tags: artifact

How many card colors are in Artifact, and how do they differ from each other?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a general rule, the colors from fastest to slowest are red, black, green, then blue. Color pairings will have according speeds, with red and black decks generally being very aggressive, green and blue decks being generally pretty slow, and everything else being between the two. There are exceptions to this, but keeping this in mind helps you to understand the kind of game plans that color pairings will favor.

**Red** is all about the early game, and winning combat, but has weaknesses in having trouble getting damage through later and killing problematic units (this is why Axe is so damned good, he gets around this problem).

Adding **+black** gives you more mobility and ways to get a few things out of the way, and also offers Siege abilities.

Adding **+blue** gives you the ability to wipe their board out entirely to go face.

Adding **+green** makes your heroes even harder to kill, and accelerates you into your late game plays quicker.

**Black** is all about mobility and point removal, but has weaknesses in that its heroes tend to be a tad fragile, and lacks ways to mitigate going wide.

Adding **+red** gives you extra early pressure and stability. Red heroes are also great at slowing down an entire lane alone.

Adding **+green** gives you more stability and ways to protect your fragile heroes, and offers some great late game pressure as well.

Adding **+blue** gives you board wipes to clear the path, and tricks to keep your heroes safe.

**Green** has great supporting defenses, mana acceleration, and powerful late game creeps. Its weakness lies in early game pressure and utter lack of hard removal (this is why Drow is so good, she's free pressure and her spell is good soft removal).

Adding **+red** gives you good early game pressure and extra defense.

Adding **+black** gives you removal and ways to push for more damage.

Adding **+blue** gives you board wipes to clear the way for your threats, and mana recycling for massive turns.

**Blue** is the strongest late game color, with immensely powerful spells and access to card draw and mana recycling. Its weakness is lack of stats- blue heroes are tiny and its creeps aren't big either.

Adding **+red** gives you some early game stability, letting you make some kills and not worry too much about opposing pressure.

Adding **+black** gives you options for pushing through damage and dealing with threats too big to wipe otherwise.

Adding **+green** gives you mana acceleration so you can start playing your game-winning nukes earlier, a little more early game stability, and access to some huge win conditions.

Comment: [source](https://www.reddit.com/r/Artifact/comments/a1yl42/a_few_intermediate_tips_to_avoid_simple_mistakes/eau53z3/)

Comment: Might as well at the source to the answer for completeness sake.